# Tensorflow workflow problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having problems with how Tensorflow (keras) reads the datasets I pass to it.
Can anybody give me a brief explanation of what happens when I do the following? I mean, if I want to pass an array (where each row is a song, column atribute) how should I program the input layer so I can treat every song differently, or this is what tf actually does and it's my fault?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=518))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(len(emotions), activation='softmax'))
```

**Relevant arrays info:**

- train_data: 2D  `np.array`with all the dataset information
- test_data: 1D array of every atribute of a single atribute. I pass this array to `model.predict`

**+ Context**

My question arised from the following:

I programmed the above NN so I can input (in theory) an array of 518 atributes.
However, when testing the NN, I input an array of length 518 and this error is raised:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (518,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But I don't understand what's happening, because in theory I'm passing an 1D array input, aka I give the atributes of the songs and should output x.

Hope I expressed my thoughts in a clear manner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass an array with shape (n, 518), where n is the number of samples, even if its 1

Comment: If I understand it well you have only one sample in yout test set. If so, you should reshape your data to have a (1,518) vector to feed to your NN